# How convert cin to const char*

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, char

In my program I get input via iostream:

```
char input[29];
cin >> input;
```

I need to use this input a parameter for this class that has this parameter as its constructor

```
class::class(const char* value) {
  /* etc */ }
```

Any idea on how to convert it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to pass `input` as the argument to your constructor.  A `char[]` will decay to a `char *`, which is compatible with a `const char *`.

**However:**  Streaming into a fixed-length buffer is a really bad idea (what if someone provides an input that is more than 28 characters long?).  Use a `std::string` instead (as in @George's answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
string tmp;
cin >> tmp;
foo(tmp.c_str());
```

Comment: `String` => `string` … and you should also explain why this is a better code than OP’s.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for the >> operator to know that it can only read 29 bytes.
So you must specify it explicitly:

```
char input[29] = { 0 }; // note sets all characters to '\0' thus the read will be '\0' terminated.
cin.read(input, 28);    // leave 1 byte for '\0'
```

Alternatively you can use a std string.

```
std::string word;
cin >> word;  // reads one space seporated word.

Class objet(word.c_str()); // Or alternatively make you class work with strings.
                           // Which would be the correct and better choice.
```

If you need to read a whole line rather than a word

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

Class objet(line.c_str()); // Or alternatively make you class work with strings.
                           // Which would be the correct and better choice.
```

Note in all the above you should really check the state of the stream after the read to make sure the read worked.

```
std::string word;
if (cin >> word)   // using the if automatically checks the state. (see other questions).
{
    Class objet(word);
}
```